# use setTimeout with addEventListener to recall function with same element

Tags: javascript, settimeout, addeventlistener

I have a `div` that expands and retracts to show/hide content. I'm using `button`s with `addEventListner` to show/hide the `div`. I have more then one `div` I want to show/hide and more than one set of show/hide `button`s. I'm therefore trying to reuse the same two functions that show/hide the content but with different event handlers.

The problem I'm having is passing the relevant `div id` to the function so the function knows which`div` element to show/hide for each function call. The `function` recognizes the `div id` on the first interation however when recalled by `setTimeout` the `div id` is no longer recognized. I have tried adding the variable used for `div id` to `setTimeout` without any joy.

I'm aware I can use inline javascript for this but am trying to avoid that.

Any ideas how I can solve this using external javascript as I'm trying here ?

HTML:

```
<button id='expand'>expand</button><button id='retract'>retract</button>
<div id="latinText">
    <p>...some content here</p> 
</div>
<button id='expandToo'>expandToo</button><button id='retractToo'>retractToo</button>
<div id='latinText2'>
    <p>...some more content here</p> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function divExp(elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    var h = element.offsetHeight;
    var scrollHeight = element.scrollHeight;
    var divTimer = setTimeout(divExp, 20);
    if(h < scrollHeight) {
        h += 5;
    } else {
        clearTimeout(divTimer);
    }
    element.style.height = h+'px' ;
}

function divRetract(elem2) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem2);
    var h = element.offsetHeight;
    var retTimer = setTimeout(divRetract, 20);
    if(h > 0) {
        h -= 5;
    } else {
        clearTimeout(retTimer);
    }
    element.style.height = h+'px' ;
}

document.getElementById('expand').addEventListener('click', function(){   divExp('latinText'); }, false);
document.getElementById('retract').addEventListener('click',function (){   divRetract('latinText') }, false);
document.getElementById('expandToo').addEventListener('click', function(){ divExp('latinText2'); }, false);
document.getElementById('retractToo').addEventListener('click',function(){     divRetract('latinText2'); }, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood exactly what the problem is, but it sounds like you need to pass an argument to the function you want to call with `setTimeout`?

```
var retTimer = setTimeout(function() {
  divRetract(elem2)
}, 20);
```

Comment: apologies for the lack of clarity. I've edited the question to try to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
var divTimer = setTimeout(function(){divExp(elem)}, 20);
```

instead of

```
var divTimer = setTimeout(divExp, 20);
```

than You'll pass the same element to a function, called by timeout. Otherwise You call divExp() function without parameters